# MongoDb Query to get datetime using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

My Data in MongoDb for one of the column **"EventDate"** is stored as **ISODate("2013-08-18T18:30:28Z")**

Now I want to query that MongoCollection to get all the record which have Event date as "2013-08-13".
The comparision should be only for Date and not Time.

**Please can anayone help me out of it.**

My Code looks like

```
var queryS = Query.EQ("EventDate", 2013-08-13);
var Result = mongoCollection.FindAs<TData>(queryS);
```

Comment: You can't remove the time using a normal query. You'd need to do a range.

Comment: Like this: http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/